# PDF reader as a running text / marquee

Tags: pdf, text, marquee, reader

for a neuroscientific project, 
i would like to create 
a program that reads a pdf file and presents it as a
horizontally running text (marquee).

As I am not an experienced programer, please tell me 
how you would start and whether you see an easy way to realize this program.

Comment: That's an unusual technical requirement. I suggest that you may be happier if you convert a portion of a particular .PDF page to a .PNG, and present *that* image as a horizontally scrolling marquee.

Comment: Hello, do you mean, I should make a snapshot of every line by hand or do you recommend a certain program ? Bests regards, Schneider

Comment: I'm suggesting to break the problem into two pieces: (1) either in manual or automated fashion turn .pdf into a very long .png, perhaps 100 x 10000 pixels, and (2) display a sliding cropped window of that .png.